# Truncate text in the middle, Django Template Tag

Tags: django, django-templates, tags

Is there a native way to do [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) in the middle of a long text?

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
word = '123456789'

{{ word|truncatechars_middle:4 }}
```

displays:

```
12...89
```

Answer (score 3):

Not as far as I know, but you can define one yourself by [*writing custom template filters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

In your app, you likely need to add the elements in boldface:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        text_utils.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is likely just empty. In the `text_utils.py` file, you can write:

```
# app/templatetags/text_utils.py

from django.template import Library
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def truncatechars_middle(value, arg):
    try:
        ln = int(arg)
    except ValueError:
        return value
    if len(value) <= ln:
        return value
    else:
        return '{}...{}'.format(value[:ln//2], value[-((ln+1)//2):])
```

In the templates, you can then use the template filter with:

```
{% load text_utils %}
{{ word|truncatechars_middle:4 }}
```

In case the number of characters is *odd*, it will add one extra at the end, like:

```
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 4)
'12...89'
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 5)
'12...789'
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 6)
'123...789'
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 7)
'123...6789'
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 8)
'1234...6789'
>>> truncatechars_middle(word, 9)
'123456789'
```